# Program Stuck in Duplicate Linked Mode - Lost School Work

Tags: mouse

I'm teaching an animation class using Blender, and I have had several students encounter the following problem. Somehow they lock the program into a mode where every time they **left click** it duplicates the selected object. In the bottom left of the screen the *duplicate linked* menu is frozen in place.

The only way I have found to fix it, is to reset the program to factory settings, but this loses the work they've done.
I wonder if this is a program bug, or have they just enabled a random tool/feature?

We're running Blender on Windows, and are using 3.3.1

( The photo below isn't a screenshot of the actual issue, but a close approximation )

[image: Multiple cubes, Duplicate Linked Menu in bottom left hand corner.]

Comment: Couple of questions - Are any addon's being used? Also, have the key-mappings been changed to "industry standard" by any chance?

Comment: providing a blend file with that phenomenon would be a great help...

Comment: I guess the default shortcut for Duplicate Linked (Alt+D) was changed to LMB. How to reset? RMB in 3DView > In Object Context Menu: RMB at `Duplicate Object` > In Duplicate Object Menu: LMB on `Change Shortcut`. Now you will see `Press a key` (Change Shortcut Menu). Do not click left now. This is what probably happened. Press `Alt` + `D` for the default settings.